# How do I detect if a field is polymorphic?

Tags: fields, polymorphic

I am building a package where I use child-to-parent query to get the data, and I allow users to select fields and relationships they want. This may lead to problems like [this](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000JX95QAG), or in my case when I try to select `[SELECT CreatedBy.AboutMe FROM AccountFeed]`.

I want to prevent this from happening and forbid users to select polymorphic relationships.

My current approach to detect such relationship is following

```
static Boolean isPolymorphic(DescribeFieldResult fd) {
    return fd.getReferenceTo().size() > 1
}
```

which fails to detect fields like `AccountFeed.CreatedById`, `AccountFeed.RelatedRecordId`, `AccountFeed.InsertedById` or `SocialPost.ParentId` as polymorphic and which leads to errors like `No such column as 'AboutMe' on Entity Name`.

Another way would be just to run the query and check if it fails like following

```
static Boolean isPolymorphic(DescribeFieldResult fd) {
    try {
        List<SObject> records = Database.query('SELECT ' + fd.getRelationshipName() + '.AboutMe FROM AccountFeed');
        return false;
    } catch (System.QueryException e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

however, this way looks too ugly.

Is there an effective way to detect polymorphic fields to prevent users to select them?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `isNamePointing` method to determine if a field is polymorphic (when true, it is polymorphic). Your function can be written simply as:

```
static Boolean isPolymorphic(DescribeFieldResult fd) {
  return fd.isNamePointing();
}
```

... Though at this point, you don't really need a function for this. You also don't need to burn a query.

Comment: interesting....

Answer (score 0):

FieldDefinition object has property `IsPolymorphicForeignKey` which can be queried to determine whether the foreign key includes multiple object types (true) or not (false), so the function `isPolymorphic` can be implemented in the following way

```
static Boolean isPolymorphic(DescribeFieldResult fd) {
    FieldDefinition def = [SELECT IsPolymorphicForeignKey FROM FieldDefinition WHERE EntityDefinitionId = 'AccountFeed' AND QualifiedAPIName = :fd.getName()];
    return def.IsPolymorphicForeignKey;
}
```